# UV Tile Ratio other than 1:1?

Tags: uv

How do you set UV tile to 2:1 without using UDIM? I UVed objects in RizomUV as 2:1 ratio, but can't figure out how to change UV tile without using UDIM.

Also, can you use different two different UV ratio maps in an object? For example, one is 1:1 and the other is 2:1. Thanks

Comment: As far as i know, You can't because the UV map represents points in Texture Space that range from 0.0 to 1.0. But you can resize the Texture that is inside the UV Canvas

Comment: I see, it looks that way. Thank you Emir